# How to create a function to return an equation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to create the normal random variable pdf equation.

This function would return the final computed value of pdf for a specific x.

```
def normpdf(x, mu=0, sigma=1):
#    u = (float((x-mu) / abs(sigma)))
    y = exp(-(float((x-mu) / abs(sigma)))*(float((x-mu) / abs(sigma)))/2) / (sqrt(2*pi*sigma*sigma))
    return y
```

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
def normpdfeqn(mu=0, sigma=1):
    y = exp(-(float((x-mu) / abs(sigma)))*(float((x-mu) / abs(sigma)))/2) / (sqrt(2*pi*sigma*sigma))
    return y
```

So whenever I want to use this equation for integration or differentiation, I could directly call normpdfeqn() and use the equation returned in the integrate function.

I have tried this:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
mu = Symbol('mu')
sigma = Symbol('sigma')

def normpdfeqn(mu=0, sigma=1):
#    u = (float((x-mu) / abs(sigma)))
    y = exp(-(float((x-mu) / abs(sigma)))*(float((x-mu) / abs(sigma)))/2) / float((sqrt(2*pi*sigma*sigma)))
    return y

print(integrate(normpdfeqn(), (x, -inf, inf)))
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `float`-function in sympy expressions:

```
def normpdfeqn(x, mu=0, sigma=1):
    return exp(-((x-mu) / abs(sigma))**2 / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi*sigma*sigma))

x = Symbol('x')
print(integrate(normpdfeqn(x), (x, -inf, inf)))
```

Comment: That gave me a new error... new code: http://pastebin.com/HYAyki2r ... error: http://pastebin.com/zfbksy4N

Comment: I realized that its a namespace clash error, I'm trying to solve it, thanks for helping

Comment: simple answer: don't use `from xy import *`. Import the functions you need explicitly.